# Fetching price data from different pages using PHP

Tags: php, html, screen-scraping

What's the proper way to fetch data from different URLs and displaying it on my website?
I'm using hquery.php to scrape data and it works pretty well. 
But I'd like to know if there's a more optimized way than doing this :

```
<?php
    include_once 'hquery.php';
    $doc = hQuery::fromUrl('http://example.com/Product.aspx?PID=125');
    $price1 = $doc->find('.price');
    $doc = hQuery::fromUrl('http://example.com/Product.aspx?PID=156');
    $price2 = $doc->find('.price');
    ...
?>

<td>Product1</td>
<td><?php echo $price1 ?></td>

<td>Product2</td>
<td><?php echo $price2 ?></td>
...
```

I have more than a dozen urls like those so I know there should be a faster way but I couldn't find it. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: that's the most common way, unless the website provides an Public api to query. If you want to mass process data, have an background script do the job and store information in an database then query database from your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the URL's in an array and then just iterate over them:

```
      <?php 
        include_once 'hquery.php';
        $urls =array("http://example.com/Product.aspx?PID=125","http://example.com/Product.aspx?PID=156");
        $index = 1;
        foreach($url in $urls){
             $doc = hQuery::fromUrl($url);
             $price = $doc->find('.price');
             echo "<td>Product $index</td><td>$price</td>";
             $index += 1;
       }

       ?>
```

//EDIT:
Of course this will only improve the way the code is written, and not actually speed up the page. If you want to speed it up, automate the fetching of data, save it and query your own database containing the info you have fetched.

Comment: Thank you, I guess i have to work with mysql in this case. :)